# template function string to T

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template function which reads a value from a database :

```
// Real Database access, all data are exchanged as strings.
int getDataValues(int id, string &value);

// My template function to retrive datas in several type (int, float, double...)
template <typename T> int Get_database_value(int id, T& value)
{
    string val;        

    int ret = getDataValues(id, val); // value is string

    std::stringstream  valstream(val);        

    valstream >> value;        // This line is problematic !

    return ret;
}
```

My issue is that if the value stored is a string containing a white space, for example "2020-06-15 13:39:50", the line `valstream >> value;` won't get the second part of the string and value is only "2020-06-15" instead of the whole date and time.

How can I change my code to get strings with white space and keep the template functionality ?

Comment: you do not necessarily have to change anything on this code to make reading the date possible. What is `T` in that case?

Comment: In this very case, `T` is a char[1024]

Comment: did you try with std::noskipws ? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws

Comment: Maybe just `std::strncpy(value, val.c_str(), val.length());` will solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

You do not necessarily have to change anything on the code you posted to read eg `"2020-06-15 13:39:50"`. Anyhow a date is not a `char[1024]`, so if you define a

```
struct date {
    std::string ymd;
    std::string time;
};
```

Then you can supply an `operator>>` for it:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in,date& d){
    in >> d.ymd;
    in >> d.time;
    return in;
}
```

And use your `Get_database_value<date>`. Alternatively use `getline` to read a full line and parse the line as needed (however also that I would do in dedicated `operator>>`, not in the `Get_database_value`).

Comment: This is a good answer for the date example but I need something more generic for all string datas

Comment: @grorel I dont really understand. Your `Get_database_value` is already the generic solution. It works for all types `T`, provided that there exists a `operator>>` that does what you want. Not sure if you misunderstood. I am not suggesting to replace your `Get_database_value` with the code in my answer, but rather the code in my answer is all that is needed to make `Get_database_value` also fine with the example

Comment: Yes, Get_database_value is actually the generic solution, it has to work for every string with one, several or without white space. Your solution is not suitable for me because it does care about what's in the string whereas I just need to transfer the whole string whatever is inside

Comment: @grorel in that case you can simply use `val` directly. I suppose `getDataValues(id, val)` assigns the complete string to `val`, so you do not need a stream or anything, just return `val` directly

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found. Specialize a function for string and an other one for all others :

```
// anything but std::sting
template <typename T> 
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, std::string>::value> Get_database_value(int id, T& value)
{
    string val;        
    int ret = getDataValues(id, val);        
    std::stringstream  valstream(val);           
    valstream >> value;  
}

// This case for std::sting
template <typename T> 
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, std::string>::value> Get_database_value(int id, T& value)
{
    getDataValues(id, value);
}
```

Comment: if this is what you want then you could directly call `int ret = getDataValues(id,value);`, no?

Comment: The real prototype of `getDataValues` is more complex, I have minimized it to focus on the problem. Also with this solution, I have only one function to read from the database